# ImportError: No module named msg

Tags: ros, actionlib, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm a new ROS user and tried to use actionlib. I created a new package 'tuck_arms_server' and defined the message in .action file. After compiling the package, the msg folder is automatically created. But then my python code, I wanted to do this: "import from tuck_arms_server.msg import *", but I got the error: ImportError: No module named msg.

some relevant lines in my code:
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('tuck_arms_server');

in CMakeLists.txt:(just followed the tutorial)

```
rosbuild_find_ros_package(actionlib_msgs)
include(${actionlib_msgs_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/actionbuild.cmake)
genaction()
```

also added this line to the manifest file:

```
<depend package="actionlib_msgs"/>
```

So why cant it recognize msg in my package tuck_arms_server ? Thanks in advance.:-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30545/importerror:-no-module-named-msg/) by [fangyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2059/fangyi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-09**:
You wrote "import from tuck_arms_server import *", which is not valid Python. Is that what you meant? (If not, you should probably edit the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Mac is right: Your import syntax is incorrect.  Please see [the rospy tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber)  for correct syntax.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0